# How to replace text after # into <div> in PHP?

Tags: php

Here is an example where user write '#'.

```
Lorem ipsum # dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
# At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
# invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
```

And the script should replace everything after the hashtag into the content of the `<div>`.

Another problem is that only of beginning the new lines who written # can converts into `<div>`

```html
Lorem ipsum # dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
<div>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor  
<div>invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
```

This does not work properly, it just replace only one hash or replace too much

```php
$test = preg_replace("/(.*)# (.*)/", "$1<div>$2</div>", $text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use start and end-of-line markers (`^` and `$`) to ensure you only get `#` at the start of the line. Here's an example:

```
$test = preg_replace("/^\s*(#\s*)(.*)$/m", "<div>$2</div>", $text);
```